# Proxy soap service with spring integration

Tags: spring, soap, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-http

I am trying to proxy my soap service using spring integration

What I want to do is:

1. Receive a SOAP request on a certain endpoint
2. Intercept request header and body, log them
3. And without modification, forward this request to the soap service

I read the answer to almost same question here, in which it is said:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow httpProxyFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Http.inboundGateway("/service"))
            .handle(Http.outboundGateway("/service/internal")
                            .expectedResponseType(String.class))
            .get();
}
```

but I could not find any hint with #2 (request header and body)

How can I intercept request body and header?
And is it possible to generate wsdl for proxy service as well?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if `.log()` before your `.handle()` can help you. There are plenty of overridden variants.

I'm not sure that WSDL generation is somehow valid functionality for this kind of service. Perhaps you mean to expose a WSDL url as it is possible with Spring WS. I guess you proxy solution still can delegate and propagate that functionality.

Comment: Can you give some hint about how to expose wsdl url for this proxy service?